# Contest math question about logarithmic and exponential functions

Tags: functions, logarithms, contest-math, exponential-function, recreational-mathematics

**Here's the question I'm trying to solve:**

*For what value of $k$ is the function $f(x)=k^x$ tangent to $g(x)=\log_k(x)$?*

**My Attempt:**

Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverses of each other and are therefore symmetrical on $y=x$, the tangent point must occur when $y=x$. By setting $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$, we get $x=k^x$ and $x=\log_{k}x$ but these two equations are pretty much the same since $x=k^x \Rightarrow x=\log_{k}x$ so I can't find any unique solution. Most other approaches I've tried pretty much get me to the same two equations.

I've tried taking the derivative of both functions which have to be 1; $f'(x)=\ln(k)k^x=1$ and $g'(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(k)x}=1$ and since previously $k^x=x$ we have $x \ln(k)=1$ but we get the same issue where we get two equivalent equations.

After graphing it and trying to reverse engineer the answer I found that $1.4<k<1.5$ however this doesn't seem to correspond with any value one might expect either for example $\frac{e}{2}\approx 1.36$ or $\sqrt{e}\approx1.67$ or $\sqrt[3]{e}\approx 1.39$.

Note that this is a math competition question so should in theory (for this competition) be doable in about 5 minutes so I'm sure there's a trick to it that I have't figured out. (maybe Lambert W although I doubt it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it goes:

As $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverse of each other, for them to be tangent at one point, The slope at their point of intersection must be "$1$"

Let them meet at point $(x_1,y_1)$

hence, $f(x_1)=g(x_1)=x_1$ because, they both are also tangent to line $y=x$

putting the values

$$
k^{x_1} = \frac {\ln(x_1)}{\ln(k)}=x_1 
\tag{1}
$$

now derivative of both curves at $x=x_1$ must equal "$1$"

$$
f'(x_1) = g'(x_1) = 1
$$

substituting values

$$
k^{x_1}\ln(k) = \frac{1}{x_1\ln(k)} = 1
\tag{2}
$$

using this, $$
x_1 = \frac{1}{\ln(k)}
\tag{3}
$$

substitute

$x_1 = \frac{1}{\ln(k)}$ in Equation (1)

hence

$$
\frac{\ln\Bigl(\frac{1}{\ln(k)}\Bigr)}{\ln(k)} 
= \frac{1}{\ln(k)}
$$

by cross multiplying terms

$$
\ln\biggl(\frac{1}{\ln(k)}\biggr) = 1
$$

hence

$$
\frac{1}{\ln(k)} = e
$$

$$
\ln(k) = \frac{1}{e}
$$

which gives

$$
k = e^{\frac{1}{e}}
$$

substituting value of "$k$" in function yields

$$
f(x) = e^{\frac{x}{e}}
$$
and
$$
g(x) = e\ln(x)
$$

Answer (score -1):

$f(x)=k^x. g(x)=\log_k (x) = \frac{\ln x}{\ln k}$

They intersect: $k^x=\ln x/\ln k$

Their slopes match: $\ln k \cdot k^x = \frac{1}{x \ln k}=1$

$\implies x= 1/\ln k $

$\ln k \cdot e^{x \ln k}=1$

$\implies \ln k = 1/e\implies k=e^{1/e}\approx 1.444668$

---

$\ln k\cdot  e^ {x \ln k}=\frac{1}{x \ln k}$

$x \ln k = W(1/\ln k)$

$\ln xe^{\ln x}=1/\ln k $

$\ln x = W(1/\ln k)$